ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: initial." "testbench.sv" 50 7
I am not able to find the exact reason for the error here.  Can anyone help me?
`include "uvm_macros.svh"
import uvm_pkg::*;

class my_driver extends uvm_driver;
    `uvm_component_utils(my_driver)

     function new(string path, uvm_component parent);
        super.new(path,parent);
     endfunction

  task run1();
    `uvm_info("DVR","INFO LEVEL",UVM_DEBUG);
    `uvm_warning("DVR", "WARNING LEVEL");
    `uvm_error("DVR","ERROR LEVEL");
    #10;
    `uvm_fatal("DVR","FATAL LEVEL");
  endtask

  task run2();
    `uvm_error("DVR1","Count of erros = 1");
    `uvm_error("DVR1","Count of erros = 2");
    `uvm_info("DVR1","simulation quit after 3 errors",UVM_DEBUG);
    `uvm_error("DVR1","Count of erros = 3");
  endtask

endclass

class my_environment extends uvm_env;
  `uvm_component_utils(my_environment)

  function new(string path, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(path,parent);
  endfunction
  
  initial 
    begin
      my_driver my_dvr_obj;
      my_dvr_obj = new("DVR",null);
      my_dvr_obj.run1();

      my_driver my_dvr_obj_new;
      my_dvr_obj_new = new("DVR1",null);
      my_dvr_obj_new.set_report_max_quit_count(3);
      my_dvr_obj_new.run2();
    end

  task my_task();
    `uvm_info("MY_ENV","Verbosity level is UVM_DEBUG in Environment",UVM_DEBUG);
  endtask

endclass

module tb;
  initial begin
    my_environment new_env_obj;
    new_env_obj = new("MY_ENV",null);`your text`
    new_env_obj.set_report_verbosity_level_hier(UVM_DEBUG);
    new_env_obj.my_task();
  end
endmodule

I am trying to change the verbosity of the my_environment to UVM_DEBUG.

It is illegal to use the initial keyword inside a class.  When I try to compile your code with the Cadence simulator, I get a much more helpful error message:
xmvlog: *E,DECINM : Declaration is only valid within a module, interface, or a program block.

When you don't understand an error message, you can try to compile your code on other simulators on EDA Playground.
You could add the code from your initial block into the new function.
